# How to load a xml file in php so that i can use xpath on it?

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I have a problem with php,
If I implement this code below then nothing will be happen.

> ```
> $filename = "/opt/olat/olatdata/bcroot/course/85235053647606/runstructure.xml";
> if (file_exists($filename)) {
>  $xml = simplexml_load_file($filename, 'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);
>  // $xpath = new DOMXPath($filename);
> }
> $doc = new DOMDocument();
> $doc->loadXML($xml);
> $xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
>
> $res = $xpath->query('/org.olat.course.Structure/rootNode/children/org.olat.course.nodes.STCourseNode/shortTitle');
>
> foreach ($res as $entry) {
>     echo "{$entry->nodeValue}<br/>";
> }
> ```

If I change the contents of $xml in the content with the content of the $filename

> ```
> $xml = '<org.olat.course.Structure><rootNode class="org.olat.course.nodes.STCourseNode"> ... ';
> ```
>
> then it works, so i think that there is something wrong with loading methode of the xml file, 
>   I've also tried to load the xml file as a Domdocument but it won't work neither.
>   And in both cases, it does work if I collect xml data via xml
>   for example this works
>
> echo $Course_name = $xml->rootNode->longTitle;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`loadXML` takes a *string* as input, not the return value of `simplexml_load_file`. Just use `file_get_contents` to get the (full) contents of a file as *string*

Comment: It works - Thank you.
You've told the answere while i was searching for more than 2 hours
Thank you again :)